# Erlang and Phoenix bug, low_entropy with Docker

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am currently trying to set up a Phoenix server in a docker container. The  creation of the Docker image works well, but when trying to run it, it exits with an error :

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,satisfaction,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Satisfaction.Endpoint',{'EXIT',{low_entropy,[{crypto,strong_rand_bytes,1,[{file,\"crypto.erl\"},{line,436}]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Adapter',config_children,2,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/endpoint/adapter.ex\"},{line,34}]},{'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Adapter',start_link,2,[{file,\"lib/phoenix/endpoint/adapter.ex\"},{line,18}]},{supervisor,do_start_child,2,[{file,\"supervisor.erl\"},{line,358}]},{supervisor,start_children,3,[{file,\"supervisor.erl\"},{line,341}]},{supervisor,init_children,2,[{file,\"supervisor.erl\"},{line,307}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,240}]}]}}}},{'Elixir.Satisfaction',start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,satisfaction,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Satisfaction.Endpoint',{'EXIT',{low_entropy,[{crypto,strong_rand_byt
```

I cannot figure why, does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Best regards,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650842/how-to-handle-low-entropy-exception-of-cryptostrong-rand-bytesn

Comment: Thanks for it does not give any solution.

Comment: Try this `docker run -v /dev/urandom:/dev/urandom -v /dev/random:/dev/random <imageid>` and see if it helps?